# GAE PHP Local Development: Task Queue Not Working

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cakephp-2.0

My tasks work great when deployed, but on Local Dev, no luck. No errors. It just acts like the tasks fired off as expected. They don't even show up in the task queue in my Local Admin Console. Although, the Queue Names from my queue.yaml show up there.

Here is my local dev environment:

- Python 2.7.6
- CakePHP
- Windows 8.1

In my console logs, I can see that the post from the task is being made, only it's going through the default target, rather than the api target, as I defined in queue.yaml. I know the following python command will update the queue data on production (run from my console, in the folder containing queue.yaml):

```
appcfg.py update_queues .
```

---

### 2 Questions:

---

**1. Is there a command to update the queue data for local dev?**

**2. Is there any other way to tell the task to fire from a specified target?**

Below is my `queue.yaml` file:

```
queue:
- name: processRankingsFile
  rate: 5/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 7
    task_age_limit: 2d
    min_backoff_seconds: 600
    max_backoff_seconds: 2400
  target: api
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a task add a `"Host: api"` header to the options array:

```
    $task = new PushTask('run_on_backend.php', [], [ 'header' => 'Host: api']);
```

This should run this task on the `api` module.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push#PHP_Task_execution) say:

> The "Host" header that you can add to the $options when you create a PushTask.

Comment: I had a lot of faith in this working, but alas it did not for me. But I believe it would have fixed it if my server were set up properly. Therefore, I've marked it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. The only way to update queue config is to restart the local dev_appserver.
2. You can specify queue name via PushTask's constructor or PushTask:add(). See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/files/google.appengine.api.taskqueue.PushTask and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push#PHP_Using_push_queues